# modular function for getting total shipping sizes

Tags: php

A site I'm currently building uses a shipping company that has three different pallet sizes for shipping: up to 250kg, up to 500kg and up to 1000kg.

While I've built a function to get the configuration of pallets needed for the total weight, it is kind of hard coded and I'm looking for a more modular way of working this out if I throw in another pallet weight at a later date or use the same functionality for another project.

What I have is this:

```
$sizes = array(
        array('desc'=>'large','limit'=>1000),
        array('desc'=>'medium','limit'=>500),
        array('desc'=>'small','limit'=>250)
        );
foreach ($sizes as $k=>$v) {
    $pallets[$v['desc']] = 0;
}

echo $total_weight = 2280;
echo "<hr />";

function pallet_size($weight) {

    global $sizes, $pallets;

    if ($weight > $sizes[1]['limit']) {
        $pallets[$sizes[0]['desc']]+=1;
        $weight-=$sizes[0]['limit'];
        pallet_size($weight);
    } elseif ($weight > $sizes[2]['limit']) {
        $pallets[$sizes[1]['desc']]+=1;
        $weight-=$sizes[1]['limit'];
        pallet_size($weight);
    } elseif ($weight < $sizes[2]['limit'] && $weight>0) {
        $pallets[$sizes[2]['desc']]+=1;
        $weight-=$sizes[2]['limit'];
        pallet_size($weight);
    } elseif ($weight<=0) {
        print_r($pallets);
        exit();
    }
}

pallet_size($total_weight);
```

Perhaps I'm just going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a table that will allow you to add additional weight information in the future. Just query the data if needed. In this way you can easily add/edit/remove weights and don't have to edit your codes

Try this codes:

```
foreach($sizes as $key => $value){

       if($weight > $value[$key]['limit']){
           $pallets[$value[$key]['desc'] += 1;
           $weight -= $value[$key]['limit'];
           pallet_size($weight);
       }else if ($weight < $value[$key]['limit']){
           $pallets[$value[$key]['desc'] += 1;
           $weight -= $value[$key]['limit'];
           pallet_size($weight);
       }else if ($weight <= 0){
           print_r($pallets);  
           exit();
       }

 }
```

Comment: the data will be in a table, it's not the array/result set of pallet weights I'm worried about editing, it's the function to calculate what configuration I don't want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this out now:

```
$sizes = array(
            array('desc'=>'large','limit'=>1000),
            array('desc'=>'medium','limit'=>500),
            array('desc'=>'small','limit'=>250),
            array('desc'=>'parcel','limit'=>25)
            );
foreach ($sizes as $k=>$v) {
    $pallets[$v['desc']] = 0;
}

echo $total_weight = 1023;
echo "<hr />";

function pallet_size($weight) {

    global $sizes, $pallets;

    for ($i=0;$i<count($sizes);$i++) {
        if ($i==(count($sizes)-1)) {
            if ($weight < $sizes[$i]['limit'] && $weight>0) {
                $pallets[$sizes[$i]['desc']]+=1;
                $weight-=$sizes[$i]['limit'];
                pallet_size($weight);
            } elseif ($weight<=0) {
                print_r($pallets);
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            if ($weight > $sizes[($i+1)]['limit']) {
                $pallets[$sizes[$i]['desc']]+=1;
                $weight-=$sizes[$i]['limit'];
                pallet_size($weight);
            } elseif ($weight<=0) {
                print_r($pallets);
                exit();
            }
        }       
    }
}

pallet_size($total_weight);
```

Comment: dont add count($sizes) to your for loop. It will make the script slower, each time the loop is called it will also call the count function. just create a variable outside the loop for the count, $total_number_sizes = $count($sizes) then for($i=0;$i<$total_number_sizes;++$i) [Note: placing ++ before the variable will also make the script compile faster]

Comment: try the one i've provided in my answer above to see if it works for you

Comment: yes, you're correct I shouldn't do the count() function on every loop. didn't know that about putting the ++ before the iteration, thanks. btw, your code below was an unending loop... thanks anyway though